# Select Closest Matching DOM Elements

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for help coming up with a jquery selector that will find all matching elements underneath a root element with the constraint that there is not another matching element between the candidate element and the root element.

Here's some pseudo html to clarify what I am after

```
<table id='root'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <!-- I want this table -->
                    <table id='A'>...</table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <!-- And this one -->
                    <table id='B'>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div>
                                        <!-- But not this one, it's inside another -->
                                        <table id='C'>...</table>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the above case, I would be looking for a selector that would give me tables A and B, but not C (since table B is between it and the root table).

Edit: to clarify further, I included Id's merely so I could refer back to them in the question. I won't know the id's of the elements I'm after and there will be an arbitrary number of them with arbitrary depth.

Comment: They all have ID's, so that's easy `$('#A, #B')` <- Tada. Now you just have to write valid HTML, and it will work most excellently.

Comment: *"Here's some pseudo html..."* It's so "pseudo" that it's unclear what you're trying to do. Is that a table with a div inside it with a table inside *that* with a div (invalidly) inside **that** containing another table? That's what you literally have. Or are the `divs` meant to be siblings? Or...?

Comment: So you want all tables that have no tables as parents?

Comment: Ok, that was a 'hastily' constructed example. I'll edit it into something more reasonable.

Comment: Actually, I want all descendant tables of the root table that don't have any other ancestor tables.

Comment: @grin0048: *"Actually, I want all descendant tables of the root table that don't have any other ancestor tables."* ***Any*** other? Or only none within the root? E.g., what if the root itself is inside a table? (I'd like to assume that that's not what you have in mind, as none would match, but you wouldn't believe the questions people ask...)

Comment: Yes, none within the context of the root table, thank you.

Comment: @grin0048: Your updated example puts table `B` *within* table `A`. All due respect, how hard was it, really, to post a question with the correct structure? Originally, ideally, or at least after it was pointed out how unclear you were being? You're asking for help, simple courtesy says take the time to be clear.

Comment: My apologies for the poor execution of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner: find all tables under `#root` then remove "grandchildren" tables using `.not()`:

```
$('#root table').not( $('#root table table'))
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: +1 Nice and simple. (So much so, I don't recall seeing it when posted!)

Comment: But maybe not the fastest. Or who knows.

Comment: Who knows, but it's unlikely to matter. If/when it matters, one can worry about it then. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just get all the tables inside `root`, then filter out any that doesn't have #root as the `closest()` table. You'll have to start at the parent, as `closest()` starts with the current element, which is also a table :

```
$('#root table').filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent().closest('table').prop('id') == 'root';
});
```

It should be noted that a DIV is not a valid child of a table, so this won't work with the current markup, as it's ***totally invalid***.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#root > div > table')
```

This will return all tables that are direct children of a div element that is also direct child of #root. So, it won't return #C because the div parent is not a direct child of #root

Comment: The > operator matches only direct children of a parent element. So will match all the tables that are direct child of any div element that is also a direct child of #root. That's why the #C table won't be returned.

Comment: @ Sim: To improve your answer, use the "edit" link, not a comment.